# How many people need to turn up to be sure of making at least one team?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, elementary-probability

[image]

So pigeonhole principle states when there are m objects to be divided into n sets then at least one contains r+1 objects. i.e m > nr 
In this question the m objects should be 12 months in 5 people so 12>5*3?

How do you arrive at 49?

Answer (score 2):

The value we are trying to find in this problem is $m$, the number of people required to have at least one team of five people.

We want at least one team with $5$ players, so $r + 1 = 5 \implies r = 4$.

The number of teams is the number of months, so $n = 12$.

Hence, according to your formula $m > 12 \cdot 4 = 48$.  The smallest such value is $m = 49$.

Comment: How can number of teams be number of months?

Comment: It says that the members of each team must be born in the same month of the year.  Hence, the number of possible teams is equal to the number of months.

Answer (score 2):

There are 12 possible months. Let's imagine "the worst" situation for finding team quickly: each new person has the most "unpopular" month of birth - so, ppl are distributed "uniformly" between month. How many ppl you need to have 4 of each type? 4*12=48. And then any new person (+1) will have 1 of 12 possible months of birth and 4+1=5 (team is made). 
If ppl won't distribute uniformly, then you will need 48 or less (because if one group has 3, then another has 5). 4*12+1=49 is maximum, then.